# parse jQuery like selector regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have the string

```
"foo.bar#baz"
```

and i want to get

```
["foo", ".bar", "#baz"]
```

I tried doing it with

```
"foo.bar#baz".match(/[^.]+/g).join(' .').match(/[^#]+/g).join(' #').split(' ');
```

but i think it's way too long. Do you know any shorter version?

PS:

I don't want to get

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

what i could do with

```
"foo.bar#baz".match(/[.#]+/g);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this through regex? Also, just for the record, those are CSS selectors - jQuery used them because they already existed.

Comment: @charlietfl because it seems odd to do this sort of thing through regex. And the `regex` tag does suffer from a lot of XY problems where a regex is thrown at the wrong problem. Depending on the answer to _why_ the actual answer to OP's question may just be "don't use a regular expression".

Comment: @vlaz I thought regex would be a good option to do that. But I asked for shorter versions, so answers without regex are good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead to split a string but keep the delimiting character.

```js
var myString = "foo.bar#baz";
var myRegex = /(?=[\.#])/g;
console.log(myString.split(myRegex));
```

The syntax for positive lookahead is `(?=)`

Answer (score 0):

This outputs as

```
[
  "foo.bar#baz",
  "foo",
  ".bar",
  "#baz"
]
```

```js
console.log("foo.bar#baz".match(/(.+)(\..+)(\#.+)/i));
```